# How can I use the Doctrine QueryBuilder to select a column using a foreign key?

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

I have a query to find the sum of points for an individual player in a given tournament. It works well except that the value for the "User" is returned as the foreign key id for that user.

```php
$q = $this->createQueryBuilder('s')
            ->select('IDENTITY(s.user) as user', 'SUM(s.points) as points')
            ->groupBy('s.user')
            ->andWhere('s.tournament = :tournament')
            ->setParameter('tournament', $tournament)
            ->orderBy('points', 'DESC')
        ;
```

Is there a way that I can select the user's username instead? I'd expect it's possible, instead of having to make another query for every user in the result.

Comment: try to join you "users" table on your queryBuilder ( `->join('s.user', 'user')` ) , and update your select `select('user.username as username', 'SUM(s.points) as points')`

Comment: Hey thanks @MohamedRadhiGuennichi

I figured it had something to do with joins but I don't know much about working with the database. Your example here really helped.

Answer (score 1):

Just join the user table and add username to select query:

```
$q = $this->createQueryBuilder('s')
        ->select('IDENTITY(s.user) as user', 's.username', 'SUM(s.points) as points')
        ->leftJoin('s.user','user')
        ->groupBy('s.user')
        ->andWhere('s.tournament = :tournament')
        ->setParameter('tournament', $tournament)
        ->orderBy('points', 'DESC');
```